# Contract violation when implementing stream procedure - Scheme

Tags: stream, scheme

I am implementing a procedure that takes a number n and a stream, and returns a new stream with the n first elements in the streams

```
(define (stream-take n stream)
    (cond ((stream-null? stream) 
           (the-empty-stream))
          ((= n 0) ('()))
          (else
           (cons (car stream)
               (stream-take (- n 1)
                 (force (cdr stream))
                 )))))

(stream-take 10 nats)
```

this code gives the error message

```
 =: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: (2 . #<promise>)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Comment: What are the order of arguments to your function?  What is the order in the recursive call to it?

Comment: Your result is sometimes a stream and sometimes a list. You need to make up your mind.

Comment: do you mean that I should instead of cons, car and cdr should write cons-stream, stream-car and stream-cdr? @molbdnilo

Comment: Yes, you use stream procedures with streams, and list procedures with lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
('()))
```

is not a *stream*.  It should return

```
(the-empty-stream)
```

instead.

PS:

1. Note also, I have edited your original post and added (*else* ...) at the final clause.
2. `('()))` means to call the function `'()`, which for sure won't be a function.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. About the '(); what if I want to make a procedure that takes a stream and returns a list, is it then ok to use '() if n = 0? @alinsoar

Comment: @N.A. Of course it is ok, but if you want to define a funtion `(stream)->list` you need to take care to return lists everywhere (in each particular case) and need to take care when you call it recursively not to pass lists on the places where it expects streams.